# Windows Phone MVVM: Button Command Can Execute and Command Paramtere

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to implement MVVM patter to a registeration page like this:

The Page has text boxes for username, email and password.

I want to bind the Register Button to a command using **ICommand** and **DelegateCommand** pattern.

The problem is that I want the button to be disabled if the textboxes are empty and enabled if they have text.

My **Model** is:

```
public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

My **ViewModel**:

```
public class UserViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private User user;
        public UserViewModel()
        {
            user = new User();
        }
#region Properties
.
.
.
#endregion
public ICommand RegisterCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(Register,CanRegister);
            }
        }

        private void Register(object parameter)
        {
            //TODO call the web service
        }

        private bool CanRegister(object parameter)
        {
            return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password));
        }
}
```

My **DelegateCommand** Implementation:

```
public class DelegateCommand:ICommand
    {
        //Delegate to the action that the command executes
        private Action<object> _executeAction;
        //Delegate to the function that check if the command can be executed or not
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public bool canExecuteCache;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeAction):this(executeAction,null)
        {

        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> action, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            this._executeAction = action;
            this._canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        //interface method, called when CanExecuteChanged event handler is fired
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            //true by default (in case _canExecute is null)
            bool result = true;
            Func<object, bool> canExecuteHandler = this._canExecute;
            if (canExecuteHandler != null)
            {
                result = canExecuteHandler(parameter);
            }

            return result;
        }

        //Event handler that the controld subscribe to 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


        //interface method
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _executeAction(parameter);
        }


        //rause the CanExecuteChanged event handler manually
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            EventHandler handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

        }



    }
```

and My **View**:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Username:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="txtUserName" Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Password:" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="txtPassword" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Register" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand }"   />
        </Grid>
```

What I want to achieve is to make the button disabled untill the user enters information in each **TextBox**

how can this be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing first: Returning a new `DelegateCommand` every time the property is accessed will limit your ability to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method as you won't have a reference to the same command as is bound.

So change your ViewModel to be something like this:

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private User user;
   public UserViewModel()
   {
      user = new User();
      RegisterCommand = new DelegateCommand(Register,CanRegister);
   }

   public DelegateCommand RegisterCommand {get; private set;}

   private void Register(object parameter)
   {
      //TODO call the web service
   }

   private bool CanRegister(object parameter)
   {
      return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && 
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password));
   }
}
```

The reason you can have the `RegisterCommand` property as `private set` with no PropertyChanged call as it will be instantiated before the binding occurs and doesn't need to change.

Assuming the form of the properties `UserName` and `Password` trigger the `PropertyChanged` event, you can just call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method on the `RegisterCommand` when they change.

Eg.

```
private string _userName;
public string UserName
{
    get { return _userName; }
    set
    {
        if(_userName == value)
            return;

        _userName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");

        RegisterCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

this will force the CanExecute method to re-evaluated.